# Is postgresql installed by default on MacOS?

Tags: macos, postgresql

The Uninstall app isn't working and it's been so long that I don't remember if MacOS had Postgres installed for anything before I started.  If I delete /Library/PostgreSQL will it brick my system?
I have the latest MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres is not installed by default and removing /Library/PostgreSQL won't brick your system AFAIK, have done that several times myself.